# Access of violation at address 00404094 with AssignFile();

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm just getting back into Delphi after a few months of not touching it. Just want to refresh my mind a bit.

I keep getting an access violation at the part of `AssignFile();`. What I'm doing is just reading a list of names into a rich edit via a text file.

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  k : Integer;
  MyArray : array[1..1000] of string;
begin
  k := 1;
  AssignFile(MyFile, 'names.txt');
  Reset(MyFile);
  while not Eof(MyFile) do // <-- Here is the error
    begin
      readln(MyFile, MyArray[k]);
      redOut.Lines.Add(MyArray[k]);
      Inc(k);
    end;
  CloseFile(MyFile);
end;
```

I remember finding this error multiple times over the odd times I did Delphi, but I remember not using the `CloseFile();` or `Reset();` when getting the error.

Comment: Perhaps you are reading over the end of the array. The array is needless too. One string var suffices. `redOut.Lines.LoadFromFile(...)` replaces all the code in the Q.

Comment: `MyFile` is something of a mystery too. We cannot see what it is or where it lives.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I never knew `LoadFromFile()`. I'm Just trying to remember the stuff I learnt from a horrible textbook I had last year. I suppose their way of teaching isn't the best. They say when using `AssignFile()`, the file you want it to read should be in the same folder as the project, or something (as far as I remember). Thanks for giving the `LoadFromFile()'. Makes the code much shorter!

Comment: As a general rule, don't use that Pascal IO any more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But what about when I get a question asking me to sort a list of something (eg alphabetically?) in a text file? Is there another procedure I can use instead of bubble sorting an array?

Comment: You say the problem is with one function, but in your code, you point to something else. Copy and paste your real code to avoid wasting people's time (including your own).

Comment: Yes, sorting is possible. It's orthogonal to reading files.

Comment: Just out of interest: how many months are "a few" in your question?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Not that many, I'm taking IT in school because I want to learn more about hardware than software. I come here to ask for the programming stuff that they give us (I guess I shouldn't because this place is for professional programmers, but no where else answers stuff as quickly and accurately as here. As well as StackOverFlow helped me a lot with passing IT). Sorry If i wasted your time making you read this. xD

Comment: SO is for all programmers, not just pros. Your questions are welcome here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you. I'm not very clear with asking programming questions as how they ask us to (SO), like for instance when I ask another question in the comments of my first question. English isn't my home language either so I struggle trying to explain what I want to be answered etc.

Comment: It's fine. If something isn't quite right we'll put you straight.

Comment: @link: I am not a professional programmer either. I am a dentist who likes to program. As David says, everyone's programming questions are welcome here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to see where the error originates given that code. One possibility is that you write off the end of the statically sized array.

There's no need for an array at all. You could use a single variable of type `string` to read each line.

It would all be easier like this though:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  redOut.Lines.LoadFromFile('names.txt');
end;
```