# Searching for an element in an array has no results?

Tags: delphi

Firstly, I know I'm going to get shouted at for using obsolete Delphi methods, but It was the way I was taught and I'm just practicing these things for an exam coming up.

Anyway, I'm reading a bunch of names via a textfile into an array. The user then has the option to search for a name in the text file, and it will either return that the name is there, or isn't.

Here's the code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  myFile : TextFile;
  Search : string;
  k : Integer;
  arrNames : array [1..200] of string;
  bFound : Boolean;
begin
  AssignFile (myFile, 'names.txt');

  reset(myFile);

  Search := UpperCase(InputBox('Search a Name', '', 'Tiffani Bressler'));

  k := 1;

  bFound := False;

  while not Eof(myFile) or bFound = False do begin

      Readln(myFile, arrNames[k]);

      if Search = UpperCase(arrNames[k]) then

      begin

        bFound := true;

      end;

      lblLineSearched.Caption := 'Line searched: ' + IntToStr(k);

      inc(k);

    end;

    if bFound = True then

      ShowMessage('You searched for: ' + Search + ' and it was found on line: ' + IntToStr(k))

      else ShowMessage('You searched for: ' + Search + ' and it was not found');

  CloseFile(myFile);

end;
```

The problem is as soon as I press the search button (i directly copy a name from the text file itself), i get the message saying `Name not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: Where I put the 'LabelSearched', that doesn't even change after i have searched.

Comment: (1) Put breakpoint on `while not Eof(myFile) or bFound = False do begin` (2) Run App in debugger (3) When code reaches breakpoint, check values are what you expect. (4) Press F8 and see if code steps to the line you expect. (5) Check that values change / not change in the way you expect. (6) Rinse-repeat.

Comment: Note that you're not actually searching an array. You're storing each line into an array, but you never look at any element more than once. Replace the array declaration with a single string variable: `Name: string`. Then replace each array reference `arrName[k]` with just `Name`. This way, you'll re-use a single variable since that's all you ever really need. Once you've found the index value `k`, you don't use any of the array contents again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logical expression is wrong. The equality test is binding to the whole expression. It's the same as

```
((not Eof(myFile)) or bFound) = False
```

Learn about this by studying the table of [operator precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence). Note that `=` has lower precedence than the other operators in this expression. And that `not` has higher preference than `or` which is why I added the parens around `not Eof()`.

Since `Eof` returns `False` this test always fails and the body of the `while` loop is never entered. You mean

```
not Eof(myFile) or (bFound = False)
```

But it is idiomatically poor to test booleans against true or false. So I'd do this like so:

```
not Eof(myFile) or not bFound
```

Even then that is still wrong. You need both conditions to be true to enter a new iteration. It's no good entering the loop body if `Eof` returns true. So you need this condition:

```
not Eof(myFile) and not bFound
```

Personally I think I'd try to do without the `bFound` local and use `break` to escape from the loop, but that is perhaps more a matter of personal taste.

If you want to move on from legacy Pascal I/O then you might contemplate `TStreamReader`. That will allow you to keep the same `while` loop reading one line at a time.

I'm sure I've said this before, quite possibly to you, but your array is not only pointless and wasteful, but dangerous. You consider one line at a time. Use the same `string` local variable to read each line. As it stands your code is bait for a buffer overrun error.

Ah yes, here's the question: [Access of violation at address 00404094 with AssignFile();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229850/access-of-violation-at-address-00404094-with-assignfile) Please review the answer you accepted to that question.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, the `not bFound` does make the readability better. Thanks for your fast and accurate answer :)

Comment: I like Break also. Less probability for error. I suppose he could then move the "succesful" and "unsuccesful" ShowMessages to just before the break.

Comment: Personally I would use a TStringlist

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can mistake, but is it not infinite loop if nothing will found (`bFound` always false)?

Comment: @jens TStreamReader is better in my view

Answer (score 4):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but you can use another approach - a `TStringList`.

Something like:

```
procedure Search(const aFileName: String; const aSearchString: String);
var
  index: Integer;
  sl: TStringList;    
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try        
    sl.LoadFromFile(aFileName);

    // case sensitive search
    sl.CaseSensitive := True;

    index := sl.IndexOf(aSearchString);

    if index > -1 then
      ShowMessage(Format('String found at line %d', [index + 1])) else
      ShowMessage('String not found!');

  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Nothing... I just forgot about it :)